# How do I declare ENUMs in Chapel?

Tags: enums, chapel

Building out a flexible function, and I want it to look like

```
if sensor.type == SENSOR_TYPE.DISTANCE {
  doSomthingEmotionallyDistant();
} else if sensor.type = SENSOR_TYPE.ANGLE {
  gleanAnAngelsAngle();
}
```

Do enums have to be declared at the Module level?  Can you point me to some examples or (better) provide one here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do enums have to be declared at the Module level?

Nope. They can be declared in inner scopes as well.

> Can you point me to some examples

The syntax is covered in the spec and the [quick reference sheet](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/master/_downloads/quickReference.pdf). There really aren't many great examples in the documentation right now, as far as I can tell. This might benefit from an issue or (better) a small contribution to the primers, for example.

> or provide [an example] here?

Below is your example, expanded with a working enum. Note, I've changed `.type` to `.t` since `.type` is reserved for the actual type.

```
enum SENSOR_TYPE {DISTANCE, ANGLE};

record Sensor {
  var t: SENSOR_TYPE;
}

var sensor = new Sensor(t=SENSOR_TYPE.DISTANCE);
if sensor.t == SENSOR_TYPE.DISTANCE {
  doSomethingEmotionallyDistant();
} else if sensor.t == SENSOR_TYPE.ANGLE {
  gleanAnAngelsAngle();
}

// Defined so this example will compile...
proc doSomethingEmotionallyDistant() { writeln('DISTANCE'); };
proc gleanAnAngelsAngle() { writeln('ANGLE'); };
```

You can also "use" an enum like you can with a module, to expose it's symbols to your namespace:

```
enum SENSOR_TYPE {DISTANCE, ANGLE};

use SENSOR_TYPE;

record Sensor {
  var t: SENSOR_TYPE;
}

var sensor = new Sensor(t=DISTANCE);

if sensor.t == DISTANCE {
  doSomethingEmotionallyDistant();
} else if sensor.t == ANGLE {
  gleanAnAngelsAngle();
}

// Defined so this will compile...
proc doSomethingEmotionallyDistant() { writeln('DISTANCE'); };
proc gleanAnAngelsAngle() { writeln('ANGLE'); };
```